# Boostrap 3.0 Carousel - different width images

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, carousel

I would like to use the Bootstrap 3.0 Carousel to display an image slider on my webpage. The page is here: http://wasup.si/test-bid1

The problem I have is that my images are of different width, but of the same height. What I would like is for the images to stick together. Basically, the width of the item class should be the same to that of the image. Anyone knows how I can do this?

The full carousel width should still be 100% of the page, just showing more items than just one.

Comment: I'd suggest either simply centering your current images and putting a background color behind them or maybe try and source images which are large enough to stretch full screen. Any carousel/gallery will work better with images which are all the same size.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I have no control over the source images (user upload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to use this is some other carousel

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

```
<div id="owl-demo">

  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>

</div>
```